# Use mixed authentication with Asp.Net MVC (Forms, FB connect, twitter, openId)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, facebook

I'm creating a new site and I want the users to be able to use several ways to sign in, basically the users should be able to create a new user on my site OR use Facebook connect OR use Twitter's account to log into the site.

I have seen several tutorials on using one of these methods, what I want to know is what do you think is the best approach to do this?

So far I think the best way would be to create a custom Authentication model (something like subtyping the existing authorization classes).

Is this the best approach?
Can you point me to a good example of someone trying something similar?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I blogged about something similar recently...Here's the approach I took

```
public class User {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }

    public virtual Authentication Authentication { get; set; }
}

public class Authentication {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LoginId { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

//login methods
User StandardUserLogin(string username) {
    IDataContext db = new DataContext();
    var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Authentication.LoginId == username);
    if (user != null) {
        if (user.Authentication.Password == password) {
            SetAuthenticationTicket(user);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

I would create a different login method for each type of login depending on how their authorization schemes work.

```
User OpenIdUserLogin(string username) {
    IDataContext db = new DataContext();
    var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Authentication.LoginId == username && u.Authentication.Provider == "openid");
    if (user == null) {
        //create new openid user
    }

    if (user.Authentication.LoginId == id) {
        SetAuthenticationTicket(user);
        return user;
        }
}

//openid's authentication method
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Authenticate(string returnUrl) {
    IAuthenticationResponse response = OpenId.GetResponse();

    if (response == null) {
        //make openid request here
    } else {
        var user = OpenIdUserLogin(response.ClaimedIdentifier);
    }
}
```

Btw, the two classes at the top represent my Entity Framework POCOs
The key here is the Authentication Table which is separate from the user table. It allows one user to have multiple methods of signing in. Hope this helps you get you on track.

Comment: Quick question; these methods are for OpenID, not Open Authentication which is the one that Twitter uses. Can we do the same procedure regardless of it's OpenID or Open Auth ?

Comment: Yeah, it's POCO classes are fairly generic. You might have to add a field or two but I doubt it given my limited experience with twitter you only need to store their auth token, which would be stored in the field `LoginId`. Then, you would just call a different method on different login types. So instead of OpenIdUserLogin you'd call a Twitter one. If I'm not too busy I'll add a new post to my blog about it if you're having trouble :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented OpenID login in a very similar way as you answered here and now I'm going for oAuth. I'm currently following these two links: http://bit.ly/csBrgM and http://bit.ly/i8GwDh Haven't tested yet, so It could either go really well, or really bad, but again, thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to spending a few bucks per month the [Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/accesscontrol/) provides this functionality as a drop-in membership provider for ASP.NET. This is also the basis for the new Windows 8 SSO credential flow.

Note that Twitter is not yet supported, however, because Access Control doesn't support OAuth 1.0.