# Is there an ASP.MVC 3 sample project or nuget package for Open ID / Facebook / Live authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, openid, nuget

Before I reinvent the wheel, ASP.Net MVC 3 Tools Update includes an Internet Application (with Forms based login) and Intranet Application (with Active Directory login) does anyone have an MVC 3 project template, or controller/model, or Nuget package for Open ID / Facebook / MS live based logins?

I'm capable of tracking down the API libraries for Facebook, Yahoo, Google and Microsoft and building my own, but before I start from scratch, I just wanted to see if someone already had a starter project or Nuget package that implemented that form of authentication. I'd rather support that project than start my own if I could.

Thanks :-)
Dan

Comment: ...so far, no packaged approach... but some good places to get started.

Comment: Clarification: DotNetOpenAuth does have a Nuget package. I'll load it up and look it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [DotNetOpenAuth](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/DotNetOpenAuth)

Answer (score 0):

[Nuget.org](http://nuget.org) has a gallery you can explore.  Searching for OpenID and Facebook showed several packages that will likely get you close to what you want.  I'm not sure you will find a package that does them all but you should be able to grab them individually and then setup something in your code to allow logins from each.

http://nuget.org/List/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=openid&sortOrder=package-download-count&pageSize=10

http://nuget.org/List/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=facebook&sortOrder=package-download-count&pageSize=10

[Here's how someone tackled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689269/use-mixed-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc-forms-fb-connect-twitter-openid) the traversing of logins to one auth store in his system....